# Why can not the system display the contents of the file using Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, append

I have a python that  append text files  to a list then it  read them 
 then upon user selection of this list the system must display the content of the txt file in the edit text widget.

The problem is that the system do not display the content of the file in the edit text.

I am using **PyQt5** library and separating the GUI class from the function class and  I am importing it as **pdfviewer**.

I will appreciate any help.

Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
                             QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                             QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton)

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt

import os,time
import pdfviewer
from openFileDialog import *

class pdfViewer(pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow):

    def __init__(self,PdfPreviewObj ):
        self.PdfPreviewObj =PdfPreviewObj 
        self.setupUi(PdfPreviewObj)
        self.PdfPreviewObj.show()
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.clicked.connect(self.setExistingDirectory)



            def readFile(self, currentFile):
                    currentFile = self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()
                    print(currentFile)
                    try:
                        with open(currentFile) as ctf:
                            ctfRead = ctf.read()
                            print(ctfRead)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("the selected file is not readble because :  {0}".format(e))     


                    '''
                    print the current file name based on the list index 
                    '''
                def print_item(self):
                    print(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text())

                    '''
                    add the file path to the second listWidget  where the cursor currently is. 
                    '''

        #here i try to display the file content based 
    #on the user selection for the item from the list        
         self.textEditContentPreview.append(self.readFile(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem()))
```

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

i solved  this problemm  it was need a **return** from the readFile() function

so the solution become:

```
def readFile(self, currentFile):
                    currentFile = self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()
                    print(currentFile)
                    try:
                        with open(currentFile) as ctf:
                            ctfRead = ctf.read()
                            print(ctfRead)

                            return(ctfRread) # <==== the solution
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("the selected file is not readble because :  {0}".format(e))
```